# Change position of entry types in a structure

Tags: plugin-development, structure, position

I was wondering if there's a way to change the position of elements in an entry type structure. I want to change the positions of the elements when a user logs in, so I'll write it in a plugin.

Any Ideas?

Comment: are you talking about frontend displaying the elements in a different order or in the admin panel?

Comment: Admin panel but I've found a solution

Comment: Feel free to post it here as an answer for future reference for other developers who might want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick:

```
 craft()->sections->reorderEntryTypes($entryTypeIds);
```

Where `$entryTypeIds` is an array with all the id's in the correct order